# How to create a unique array which has objects as elements?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of students and I want to create an unique array of this students. Each student has a unique id value and I want to compare with this id value.

Here is a Student object;

```
{
    "id" = "3232aab1",
    //some other properties
}
```

Comment: What would a “unique array” look like?

Comment: *"...and I want to compare with this id value."* Okay. That seems like a good place ot start. Where are you stuck? What has your research shown you? What has [searching](/help/searching) turned up?

Comment: @Ryan There must be no student which has same id value.

Comment: @hellzone: So the original can have students with the same id value? Do they have other properties? If so, how do you decide which one you want to keep?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actually I thought that Javascript can have an interface like Set in Java.

Comment: @Ryan I didn't specified so It doesn't matter.

Comment: @hellzone: Yes, JavaScript has a `Set` type as of ES6. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var Students =[
{
    "id" : "3232aab1"  //some other properties
} ,
{
    "id" : "3232aab1"  //some other properties
}, 
{
    "id" : "3232aab2"  //some other properties
} ,
{
    "id" : "3232aab3"  //some other properties
} ,
{
    "id" : "3232aab2"  //some other properties
} ];

var tmpObj = {};
var uniqArray = Students.reduce(function(acc,curr){
  if (!tmpObj[curr.id]){
    tmpObj[curr.id] = true;
    acc.push(curr)
  }
  return acc;
},[]);
console.log(uniqArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably take an approach similar to this...

```js
class Students extends Map {
    set(key, value) {
        if (this.has(key)) { throw new Error('Student already there'); }
        return super.set(key, value);
    }
}


const students = new Students();

students.set(1, { name: 'Peter' });

console.log(students.get(1));

// students.set(1, { name: 'Gregor' }); this throws
```

Comment: Every value set in that map is going to be `undefined`. (didn’t downvote btw)

Comment: This is over kill

Comment: Java us not javascript. Check the tag

Comment: @SagarV: This *is* JavaScript. Try it.

Comment: Ok. but he is not familiar with JS.  and it is very tough for him. class and such things are new concepts to javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=[];
a.push({id:1,name:"something"});
// repeat similar;
```

To access an id

```
a[index].id;
```

Sample code to search

```
var elem = 1; // id to be searched
//loop
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
  if(elem == a[i].id){
    break;
  }
}
// now a[i] will return the required data {id:1,name:"something"}
// a[i].id = > 1 and a[i].name => something
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have underscore, you can use the following

ES6
`_.uniq(Students, student=>student.id)`

ES5
`_.uniq(Students, function(student){return student.id;})`

Comment: What if OP doesn't use underscore? OP didn't tag it so would be better if it was a plain JS answer.